# Show calculated measure in row?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Desktop 9.0 on OSX. I have data (loaded from a local CSV file) that looks like this:

```
code,org,items
0212000AA,142,10
0212000AA,143,15
0313000AA,142,90
0314000AA,143,85
```

I want a chart that shows the number of items beginning with `0212` *as a percentage of all items*, for each organisation. (I mean as a percentage of the organisation's items - for example, in the above, I would like to show `0.1 (10/(10+90))` for organisation 142.)

I have been able to get part way there, by adding `org` to Columns, and `SUM(items)` to Rows. Then by adding a Wildcard filter on `code`, for `starts with 0212`.

This shows me the number of items starting with `0212`, by organisation.

But what I don't know how to do is show this divided by the value of all items for the organisation.

Is this possible in Tableau, or do I need to pre-calculate it before loading my data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to define a calculated field called **matches_code_prefix** as:

```
left(code, 4) = "0212"
```

You can also define a parameter called, say, code_**prefix** to avoid hard coding the prefix string:

```
left(code, 4) = code_prefix
```

And then show the parameter control for code_prefix to allow the user to interact with it.

If you use this new field as a dimension to separate SUM(items) according to those that match the prefix and those that don't, you can then use a quick table calculation to get the percent of total.

For example, you can place org on the Rows shelf and matches_code_prefix on the Columns shelf, and SUM(items) on the Text shelf to make a table. Then under the analysis menu, turn on grand totals for both rows and columns to see the behavior. Next, right click on SUM(items) and choose Quick Table Calc->Percent of Total. Tableau will display the percents of total in the table.

If you want the percent of total defined differently than the default, then right click on the measure again and set Compute Using to a different value such as matches_code_prefix in your case. It's usually better to set compute using to a specific field.

If you only want to display the value for the matching case, select the column header you don't want to see and choose hide. You can also turn off the grand totals from the analysis menu when you are done.

When you are confident in the values in your table, you can turn it into a bar chart for example by moving matches_code_prefix to the detail shelf and the measure to the Columns shelf.

--
The above is the drag and drop approach. If you prefer to hard code everything in a single calculated field that is calculated on the database side, you could instead define a calculation such as:

```
zn(sum(if matches_code_prefix then items end)) / sum(items)
```

Then set the default number format for that field to display as a percentage